# How to View an iframe in Phonegap without Leaving Page?

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe

In phonegap, I'm trying to iframe to the webapp hosted on a domain. The app needs to be disabled while in motion, so the index.html has the javascript that would freeze the page (IE, create an absolute div that would prevent you from touching anything inside the iframe) if moving faster than a certain speed. However, I can't seem to iframe the way normal browsers do. An iframe immediately opens in a browser window, and even with ChildBrowser installed the iframe is still separate from the parent view, so my javascript to freeze the app would no longer apply.

Is there any way to have an iframe work the way I'm trying to get it to in Phonegap?